# TeamCIty 6.5.6 build step with Runner Type="Command Line" never completes

Tags: command-line, teamcity

I am using TeamCity 6.5.6 to implement a CIT environment. I am trying to add a build step of Runner Type = "Command Line" and trying to executing the following custom cmd script

"C:\Program Files\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.9\dotfuscator.exe" /in:D:\CITTest\bin\CITTest.Lib.dll /out:D:\CITTest\Dotfuscated

But, TeamCity is never able to complete the build step and it seems it is taking forever.

Please note that, the paths and commands mentioned in the script are correct, and, the same command is successfully executed in the command prompt.

I've also tried to execute this script using a batch file from within TeamCity, but, same thing is happening.

Can any one help in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the build log to see if there are any hints?

Comment: Yes, the build log simply waits for the commend to complete, and, it waits forever. Its not that this particular command is resulting in such behavior, Any custom command script (as part of the build process) is resulting in same.

Comment: So the issue is that any command executed via command line runner hangs? Strange. Must be something in the agent environment. Should be investigated on the agent computer: may be there are some prompts, etc. open... Also, consider disabling/uninstalling antivirus software if present.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Configured the TeamCity Build Agent Service to log on an account with administrative rights. It solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use command line. For some unknown reason, Dotfuscator license checking will fail. If you use MSBuild script, you can try this: http://www.edsquared.com/2007/11/13/Integrating+Dotfuscator+Into+Team+Build+TFS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem with Teamcity 7.1 and Dotfuscator professional edition 4.9. And I tried the administrative TeamCity Build service, it still failed to run. My final action is to import Dotfuscator tasks in MSBuild script and call Dotfuscator task to do obsfucating. It works well even without administrative TeamCity Build service. Please check this link : http://www.edsquared.com/2007/11/13/Integrating+Dotfuscator+Into+Team+Build+TFS.aspx